# pushViewController not working in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am using storyboard and xib in swift 3 (iOS 10 and XCode 8). And when i load any View Controller with xib, application is crashing.

Here is the code, i am using to load View Controller on Button Action:

```
let serverViewController = ServerViewController(nibName: "ServerViewController", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(serverViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Check if you embedded your "self" viewController in NavigationViewController

Comment: @Andrew current viewController is embedded with NavigationViewController.

Comment: @BhumitMehta Here is the Exception Log :    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

Comment: @raghu829 are you sure that your nibName is correct? maybe there is the problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is too old.

Answer (score 0):

If the `ServerViewController` nibName is correct, then the problem would be that you are trying to push a navigation controller. I mean `ServerViewController` should be a `UINavigationController` subclass in which case, you can't push the navigation controller.

Comment: thanks for reply Varun. nibName is correct. I found the solution. Actually i have converted my project from swift 2.0 to swift 3.0 using XCode8 beta. So xcode 8 beta did not convert my xib files compatible with swift 3.0. XCode8 beta converts only stroryboard and .swift files. So When i removed xib and recreated with same name than it worked.